# Do device/app tokens for APNs need to be server-side encrypted?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Does the app token for APNs contain any sensitive data such that it should be saved to the database as an encrypted value, or can it be saved in plain-text safely? I.e. Do I treat it like I would treat a certificate or more like I would treat an email address?

Comment: I don't think so. Token is just for APN server to know which phone to send this notification. Each App (not in the same App Group) sees a different token. If you re-install the App, you get a new token.

Comment: That's consistent with my understanding too. Thanks!